Bluetooth Issue in Andorid trying to pair Wiimote *(rooted device)
https://github.com/timawesomeness/PairWiimote/
i need your help regarding fixing this app to make it work on A-13 , can you make it work? it does make the wiimote pair, but the error comes up "read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1" on Xlogger "same device a-10 it works like a controller and get paired too"
same device custom aosp rom andorid -10 works fine gets paired and syncs(one light starts)
when rom upgraded to a-13 it does pair in this app but it doesnt work (all lights blink infinitely)
"read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1" on Xlogger it says
i recently started working upon this.
i really dont know much of coding but yes i can update my code a bit
as i rn on andorid studio did managed to make this app compile for sdk 34
any help to make wiimote pair is appriciated!
tried to update but didnt worked

Welcome to SO, the question needs a lot of details with changes you have done, some code, etc. Please read the same: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Across each android version, there are some API and behaviour changes. The apps need to adapt to them if they need to target a new android version.
Take a look at these to begin with:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/migration
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/migration
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/migration

